# Using %cd or % run with environment variables does not work in google colab

Tags: environment-variables, ipython, google-colaboratory, cd

I set some environment variables in one cell as below:

```
# Dataset
%env DATASET_NAME=BOSSbase_1.01
%env DATASET_GDRIVE_PATH=/content/gdrive/My Drive/University/Datasets
%env DATASET_PATH=/content/Datasets

# Result
%env RESULT_PATH=/content/Results
%env RESULT_GDRIVE_PATH=/content/gdrive/My Drive/University/Results

# Code
%env CODE_PATH=/content/Code

# Run
%env EMBED_RATIO=0.8
%env EMBED_ALGORITHM=wow
%env MODEL_NAME=BOSSbase_7030_810
```

When I use `! echo $VARIABLE_NAME` in another cell I get the desired result and the content of the variable echoed correctly.
But when in one cell I use `%cd $VARIABLE_NAME` or for running a python code with `%run` I get this error message:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$CODE_PATH'
```

How can I use cd command in a cell with an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old question but without good answer. This works better and it's easier:

```
YOUR_VARIABLE = "/XXXX/XXXX/"

%cd {YOUR_VARIABLE}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot to that, you can choose the longer version.

```py
import os
path = os.environ['CODE_PATH']
os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: what should I do with %run? This is a code I cloned from github, It has a main.py file which ahould be run from terminal with some arguments. When I use %run, also, It does not use the value of the env.

Comment: You can still use %run. Only change %cd to this code.

Comment: This is my code block ```os.chdir(os.environ['CODE_PATH'] + "/steganalysis/analysis/Catalyst Kernels")
% run main.py \
--ctrp "$DATASET_PATH/BOSSbase_1.01/cover/PILresize/train" \
``` `os.chdir` works correctly but when I use %run with env, In the code I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$DATASET_PATH/BOSSbase_1.01/cover/PILresize/train'`. The code using `argparse` library

Comment: Then you need to change `%run xxx` to `get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', 'xxx')` and substitute `$DATASET_PATH` with `os.environ['DATASET_PATH']`